# How to mosaic multiple MODIS images of Multiple months using MRT tool?

Tags: remote-sensing, batch, modis, image-mosaic, modis-reprojection-tool

I have monthly MODIS images for 2001-2014. 
For few images **mosaicing with reprojection** can be done using MRT tool. However, for large number of images it's a cumbersome process.

There are multiple folder in a pattern, where each image is saved in a particular folder (representing **MONTH**) and all the months of a particular year are stored in a specific folder named after corresponding **YEAR**. Below is the example for reference

```
MODIS\Y2000\M01
Image#1
Image#2
...

MODIS\Y2000\M02
Image#1
Image#2
...
...
...
...
...

MODIS\Y2014\M12
Image#1
Image#2
...
```

Is there any way out to automate this process using MRT tool?

Answer (score 1):

I use cygwin Linux shell under Windows OS. You should install Cygwin  firstly. Then create MRT `.prm` file of single stage (this you have done for fewer images) by using MRT tool.
[image]

Put this .prm file with all modis tiles under same folder such as `test`. Open `.prm` with txt and you could modify some parameters.

```
#INPUT_FILENAMES = ( D:\2000\049\MOD09A1.A2000049.h23v04.005.2006268204857.hdf D:\2000\049\MOD09A1.A2000049.h23v05.005.2006268204906.hdf D:\2000\049\MOD09A1.A2000049.h24v04.005.2006268205301.hdf D:\2000\049\MOD09A1.A2000049.h25v05.005.2006268195439.hdf D:\2000\049\MOD09A1.A2000049.h25v06.005.2006268195239.hdf D:\2000\049\MOD09A1.A2000049.h26v05.005.2006268195515.hdf D:\2000\049\MOD09A1.A2000049.h26v06.005.2006268195738.hdf D:\2000\049\MOD09A1.A2000049.h27v06.005.2006268195209.hdf D:\2000\049\MOD09A1.A2000049.h28v05.005.2006268195532.hdf D:\2000\049\MOD09A1.A2000049.h28v06.005.2006268195152.hdf D:\2000\049\MOD09A1.A2000049.h28v07.005.2006268195415.hdf D:\2000\049\MOD09A1.A2000049.h29v06.005.2006268195305.hdf )

INPUT_FILENAME = D:\TmpMosaic.hdf

SPECTRAL_SUBSET = ( 1 1 )
#ORIG_SPECTRAL_SUBSET = ( 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 )

SPATIAL_SUBSET_TYPE = INPUT_LAT_LONG

SPATIAL_SUBSET_UL_CORNER = ( 49.999999996 77.786191329 )
SPATIAL_SUBSET_LR_CORNER = ( 9.999999999 121.851193415 )

OUTPUT_FILENAME = D:\m2000049.tif

RESAMPLING_TYPE = NEAREST_NEIGHBOR

OUTPUT_PROJECTION_TYPE = GEO

OUTPUT_PROJECTION_PARAMETERS = ( 
0.0 0.0 0.0
0.0 0.0 0.0
0.0 0.0 0.0
0.0 0.0 0.0
0.0 0.0 0.0 )

DATUM = NoDatum

OUTPUT_PIXEL_SIZE = 0.009
```

last, open cygwin shell and cd to the modis tiles folder.

```
cd  E:/modis/change/MOD09Q1/test
```

use codes as follow:

```
day=2000049      #start time 
while [ $day -le 2000081 ]   #end time serial   
do
for trl in MOD09Q1.A$day.*.hdf      # modis image file names 
do
if [ -f $trl ]
then
HDFFILES=$(ls MOD09Q1.A$day.*.hdf)
echo $HDFFILES > MOSAICINPUT.TXT
MRTMOSAIC -i MOSAICINPUT.TXT -s "1 0 0" -o MOSAIC_TMP_$day.hdf
RESAMPLE -p MOD09Q1.PRM -i MOSAIC_TMP_$day.hdf -o MOD09Q1_$day.tif

#MOD09Q1.PRM  the .prm file have saved before

let "day=day+8"    # the modis image time interval such as 8day,16day...

break
else
let "day=day+8"
break
fi

done
done
```